# AppEngine Spring Controllers not updating

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, jetty

Perhaps I am missing something really basic here, but the problem is as follows:

I have a Java class annotated as a @Controller with a method annotated with @RequestMapping and its return value with @ResponseBody. I have a web.xml configuring the Spring Servlet to handle requests. When I locally run this webapp with AppEngine Eclipse plugin (which runs it in Jetty), it works fine.

**BUT**, when I change the method to return something different, Clean, Rebuild, and Run again, it is still returning the old content. Even if I delete the Controller, it is still working.
What is going on? This happens even if I stop and restart Jetty.

PS.: Maybe I should be annotating the class as a @WebService, not a @Controller? I am new to Spring.

*I am using Spring 3.1 and AppEngine 1.7*